# How to load Firebase DB Vaule on detail activity when ListView Item Clicked

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing android application that uses Firebase Database as back End. List View items retrieved from my Json key. For example:-

```
 {
    "Player3" : {
        "LY" : "ewfw",
        "Ty" : "rwerw"
      }
 }
```

Then, "LY" and "TY" will be loaded on As list View Item(which works fine). and after What i want is when "LY" or "TY" (List View Item) clicked "ewfw" or "rwerw" will be shown on detail acitivity. The problem is only Key  is displayed on detail activity not Value. How can i load value for detail activity? 
Here is my code...

**ListItemActivity.Java**

```
public class ListItemActivity5 extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Tab4Fragment";
    //String[] values = new String[]{"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
    ListView listView;
    TextView textView;
    Array array;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutparams;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    RelativeLayout container;
    AnimationDrawable anim;
    Context context;

    //private TextView text;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_conferance, container, false);
        //text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        container = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container5);
        final TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        anim = (AnimationDrawable) container.getBackground();
        anim.setEnterFadeDuration(2000);
        anim.setExitFadeDuration(3000);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        final ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Player");
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                friends.clear();
                for (final DataSnapshot player : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.i("Player", player.getKey());
                    friends.add(player.getKey());
                    player.getValue();


                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            player.getValue();
                            //player2 = (String) String.valueOf(player.getValue());
                            //String topic = String.valueOf(player.getValue());
                            //topic = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Details.class);

                            intent.putExtra("key", String.valueOf(player.getValue()));

                            startActivity(intent);


                        }

                    });
                }
                ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        friends) {

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                        layoutparams = view.getLayoutParams();
                        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            /*YOUR CHOICE OF COLOR*/
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        textView.setTextSize(22);

                        //Define your height here.
                        //layoutparams.height = 240;

                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

                        return view;


                    }
                };
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

**Details.Java**

```
public class Details extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout container;
    AnimationDrawable anim;
    ScrollView mScrollView;
    TextView textView1;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private ListItemActivity1 mylist1;
    private DataSnapshot dataSnapshot;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    private ListItemActivity5 listItemActivity5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ab1);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //mref = new Firebase("https://tafach-love-2.firebaseio.com/");
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(intent.hasExtra("key")){
            textView1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("key"));
        }
        textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

 }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: when I put Friends.get(position) on intent getKey() will be displayed. what i want is the value of the key the be displayed

Comment: Are you getting right values from Firebase DB?

Comment: I am getting key from fire base DB but what i need is Value from Firebase DB for detail view

Comment: On list View key from Firebase DB will be loaded and when list item clicked i want corresponding Value of the key to be shown on another acitivty

Comment: I suggest take a look at this, this explains how to read data from Firebase DB https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Answer (score 0):

I have got answer for my question. I put these lines to my code on List ItemActivity and set onclickListner in ChildEventListner instead of AddEventLister...

```
 mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                final String playerName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                hy.add(playerName);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        //player.getValue();
                        //player2 = (String) String.valueOf(player.getValue());
                        //String topic = String.valueOf(player.getValue());
                        //topic = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Details.class);

                        intent.putExtra("key", String.valueOf(hy.get(position)));

                        startActivity(intent);


                    }

                });
            }
```